# Ruby on Rails - Showing bootstrap modal in show view after creating a new record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

In my show view, I have a bootstrap modal that I want to "activate" ***only*** when a new record is created.

My controller:

```
def create
    @request = current_user.requests.build(request_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        format.html { redirect_to @request, notice: 'Request was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @request }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @request.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

My current show view:

```
#msgModal.modal.fade{"aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
  .modal-dialog{:role => "document"}
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
          %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} &times;
        %h4#myModalLabel.modal-title.text-muted One last step before we are good to go :)
      .modal-body
        %h4 Share your post with your friends to start on good foot ;)
        %img{:alt => "Sixpercent", :src => "http://localhost:8888/sixpercent.png", :style => "width: 420px;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;\n"}
        %br

%button.btn.btn-success.font-bold.txt-shadow-dark{"data-target" => "#msgModal", "data-toggle" => "modal", :type => "button"}
  #{icon('commenting-o')} Sharing div activater
```

How can I manage it a clean way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Rails' 'flash' functionality. A flash is a value that is set on the user's session cookie. It lasts one page load. More details on 5.2 of this page:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

For example, you could modify your view to do something different depending on the presence of a flash. e.g:

```
- if flash[:notice] == 'Request was successfully created.' 
  #msgModal.modal.fade{"aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
    .modal-dialog{:role => "document"}
      .modal-content
        .modal-header
          %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
            %span{"aria-hidden" => "true"} &times;
          %h4#myModalLabel.modal-title.text-muted One last step before we are good to go :)
        .modal-body
          %h4 Share your post with your friends to start on good foot ;)
          %img{:alt => "Sixpercent", :src => "http://localhost:8888/sixpercent.png", :style => "width: 420px;display: block;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;\n"}
          %br
```

Hope that helps! I'm sorry if I've missed the point of what you are trying to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

if you have modal in a partial then in your view:

`<%= render 'your_partial' %>`

and then:

```
`<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
      });
    </script>
<% end %>`
```